# Querying for albums shows duplicates

Tags: android, android-sqlite, mediastore

I'm trying to list all the albums of songs available in my sd card. I did it successfully but I have a small problem. Example, if I an album "ABC", which contains 10 artists. Then, when I query for albums, it shows album "ABC" 10 times based on the artist. Album "ABC" will be displayed 10 times and each album "ABC" will contain songs of the particular artist.

It is displayed like this,

`ABC\artistA`

`ABC\artistB`........so on

What I want is it should display the album "ABC" once and when I open it all the songs of that album should be there.

Code:

```
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
    final String album_name = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM;
    final String totSongs = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS;
    final String artist_Name = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;

    final String[] columns = {  _id, album_name, totSongs,artist_Name };

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {



                id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
                Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, id).toString();
                totalSongs = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(totSongs));
                ArtistName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist_Name));
                AlbumsModel s = new AlbumsModel(id, name, albumArtUri,totalSongs,ArtistName);
                AlbumsList.add(s);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        cursor.close();
```

Comment: the way metadata is structured is `Artist-> album -> song`, so each album in each artist is treated as different.  So you will have to exclude duplicates manually.

Comment: So, how to remove duplicates?

Comment: iterate through albums, and check if it already appeared, then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `List`, you could use `Map`:

```
HashMap<String, AlbumModel> albums = new HashMap();


Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, id).toString();
            totalSongs = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(totSongs));
            ArtistName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist_Name));

            AlbumsModel album = albums.get(id);
            if(album == null){
               album = new AlbumsModel(id, name, albumArtUri,totalSongs,ArtistName);
               albums.put(id, album);
               continue;
            }
            //update album music count
            album.setTotalMusic(album.getTotalMusic() + totSongs);
            albums.put(id, album);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could display the Album/Artist with the Album only appearing once (this assumes that the cursor is sorted by Album) :-

```
    String previous_album = "";
    for (AlbumsModel am: AlbumsList) {
        if(am.getAlbumName().equals(previous_album)) {
            Log.d("ALBUMINFO","\t\t" + am.getArtistName());

        } else {
            Log.d("ALBUMINFO",am.getAlbumName() + "\t" + am.getArtistName());
        }
        previous_album = am.getAlbumName();
    }
```

This would follow your code and write the output to the log (obviously you would tailor this to suit) e.g. :-

```
01-24 20:54:21.705 2125-2125/albums.so.so48422731albums D/ALBUMINFO: ABC    ArtistA
01-24 20:54:21.705 2125-2125/albums.so.so48422731albums D/ALBUMINFO:        ArtistB
01-24 20:54:21.705 2125-2125/albums.so.so48422731albums D/ALBUMINFO:        ArtistC
```